# finding double entries in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, openpyxl

- I pull data from multiple excel and write it back to an aggregated excel file

so I have a list of tuples and each tuple consists of two values like this:

```
tuple = (entity-ID, debitor-name)
list = [tuple1, tuple2, ..., tupleN]
```

So it can happen that there are multiple entries with the same debitor-name but with different entity-ID. I want to find all entries where the debitor-name is equal and then merge the diffrent entity-IDs into a list. Context is that there are multiple entities within my company who can all have a credit relation to the same debitor-name.
I hope this is understandable.

```
for deb in debitor_list:
    if deb not in agg_debitor_list:
        agg_debitor_list.append(deb)
```

This already filters for double entries within a certain entity so for example my debitor_list has following entries:
`[("1", "X AG"), ("1", "X AG"), ("1", "Z AG"), ("2", "X AG"), ("2", "X AG")]`
it gives me `[("1", "X AG"), ("1", "Z AG"), ("2", "X AG")]`
as result I need something like this `[(["1", "2"], "X AG"), (["1"], "Z AG")]` to write in back in the aggregated excel file.

Comment: agg_debitor_set = set(debitor_list) would be more efficient for what you've already done (since sets don't have repeated entries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want (no need to first create agg_debitor_list, redundancy is taken care of); note that for "Z AG", it returns ['1'] and not '1' like in your desired output, but this can be addressed if necessary.

```
debitor_list = [("1", "X AG"), ("1", "X AG"), ("1", "Z AG"), ("2", "X AG"), ("2", "X AG")]

def crunch(dlist):
    ddict = {}
    for tup in dlist:
        # if the key is not present in ddict, create it with an empty set for value
        if not ddict.get(tup[1]):
            ddict[tup[1]]= set()
        # adds the value to the set of values for that key (redundant values will be "merged")
        ddict[tup[1]].add(tup[0])
    # returns the dictionary in the desired format
    return [(list(b),a) for a,b in ddict.items()]

crunch(debitor_list)
# [(['1', '2'], 'X AG'), (['1'], 'Z AG')]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I stated the wrong output (['1'], 'Z AG') is the right output!

Comment: You're welcome; in the future, keep in mind that sets and dictionaries only hold unique values (keys for dicts), which provides a way to deal with redundant entries.

Comment: Yes, I will need some time now to understand your code :D

Comment: I'll add comments to help you.

Comment: So kind! Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can now work with a dict that the key is debitor-name and the value is a list of entity-ID

```
agg_debitor_list =  [("1", "X AG"), ("1", "Z AG"), ("2", "X AG")]
debitor_to_ids = dict() 
for val, key in agg_debitor_list: 
    debitor_to_ids[key] = debitor_to_ids.get(key, []) 
    debitor_to_ids[key].append(val)
    
print(debitor_to_ids)

> {'X AG': ['1', '2'], 'Z AG': ['1']}
```

Comment: thank you sir! can I write it into a pandas df for a nice overview since I have a very high amount of entires.

Comment: finaldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(debitor_to_ids, orient='index') is this a nice representation?

Comment: @BlankerHans you can transform it to a df in a single command
df = pd.DataFrame(debitor_to_ids)
while I'm no expert in pandas nor its performance